# Stuck on detecting COM port when trying to upgrade Android using Smart Phone Flash Tool

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, flashtool

I have Goophone i5c (iPhone 5C clone, MTK6572 chipset, non-removable battery), and I'm trying to upgrade my Android.

I have installed:

- Smart Phone Flash Tool
- adb-setup.exe
- MT65xx USB VCOM drivers

I still can't upgrade my Android. Most guides require to remove the battery, and I can't remove my battery as it's stick like the original iPhone battery. I also watched [this video on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tqaknYOp3c) and tried it and nothing happens, it's still stuck on detecting COM port.

[image: SPFT stuck on detecting COM port]

As per checking my `adb devices`, it seems my device is detected.

[image: result of adb devices]

Answer (score 2):

I'll be answering my question.

I downloaded [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) and I deleted all COM ports that are open. I also did removing my USB controllers on my Device Manager. I restarted my computer to reload all the drivers; then opening the flasher generates a new COM port, clicking the upgrade and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that your ADB drivers are working.

Just run following command from where you have installed ADB

> adb devices

If not detected try manually updating your phone ADB drivers.
Install generic drivers here. [link](http://www.droidiser.com/2012/11/how-to-install-drivers-for-any-android.html)

If not try the following [Post 1 #Troubleshooting part](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2033788)

Once you are sure that ADB is working...

Follow steps given in this [Post 1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2466694)

Comment: I'd pdanet on my local, I did update to my post and my device is detectable. What do you mean flashing is a breeze?

Comment: The only things resulting in error in flashing is "driver error" and "wrong files"

Comment: Check the updated link..